# Travel into NYC on New Years Eve

Tags: new-york-city, public-holidays, jfk, traffic

Does anyone know when the traffic into NYC from the north (eg i 95) starts to get heavy on New Year's Eve?

I am actually going to JFK for an evening flight via the Whitestone Bridge.

Comment: My condolences on having to celebrate New Year's in the air. :(

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have too many issues getting to JFK via points North - your route doesn't really intersect with any of the main routes into Manhattan, which is where the NYE traffic will be headed for the most part.

That said, you may want to take the Throggs Neck instead of the Whitestone -  check traffic while heading south on 1010 or 880 or your resource of choice, but I suspect Throggs Neck->Cross Island->Belt will get you to JFK a bit faster if you're coming south along 95.

Comment: Though I agree that you shouldn't expect any problems getting to JFK today via Whitestone and Van Wyck, You shouldn't discount LIE as a way into Manhattan.

Comment: Why would you even be getting on to the LIE to get from the Bronx to JFK Airport? Either you take the Whitestone Bridge to the Van Wyck or you take the Throggs Neck to the Cross Island to the Belt. I mean, I suppose you *could* take the Whitestone to the Clearview to the LIE to the Van Wyck, but that's... not a good route.

Comment: You won't take LIE coming from Whitestone, but traffic from LIE, Grand Central Pkwy, and Queens Blvd, can bog down Van Wyck.  Having said that it's not likely to happen today.